# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at runtime when accessing swift array

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, xcode6

Im quiet confused about the behavious of swift arrays. In the following example I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at runtime when I am trying to add a new element to the array inboxDocuments.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow

    var inboxDocuments:[ArchiveDocumentFile] = []

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        var docFile = ArchiveDocumentFile(newFile: "")
        inboxDocuments.append(docFile)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Surprisingly when I am changing the type of the Array to be an String array

```
var inboxDocuments:[String] = []
```

and then trying to add a String, everything works fine.

```
inboxDocuments.append("docFile")
```

What am I doing wrong, so my array of a custom class type does not work?

I am currently using XCode Beta 3

EDIT 1:

Here is a screeshot of the debugger complaining.

[image: Error in debugger]

EDIT 2:

After further investigation it seems like the problem is an NSArrayController I have bound to that array. I use it for providing data to an NSCollectionView.

I can bind the arrayController to the array. Works fine.

I can bind the collection view to th controller. Works fine. The (not filled with values) entries appear in the correct count.

But when I bind the values of my Object to the views labels I get the above error at runtime... Strange.

EDIT 3:

I solved the problem...
The bound value in ArchiveDocumentFile was a constant (declared with let). When I change that to var it works quiet fine. The problem is possibly, because a constant is not KVC compliant. But why does that cause such an error?

Comment: Are you sure it's not this causing the error `var docFile = ArchiveDocumentFile(newFile: "")`?

Comment: Yes, in the debugger I can see the correct instance of docFile and it's correctly filled with the expected values. Added a screenshot of the debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691563/ios8-beta-3-spritekit-exc-bad-acces-when-running-on-device/24708514#24708514

Try doing a clean on the project.

Comment: I did a clean but that did not change the situation. I solved my problem (see Edit 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem... The bound value in ArchiveDocumentFile was a constant (declared with let). When I change that to var it works quiet fine. The problem is possibly, because a constant is not KVC compliant. But why does that cause such an error?